# python - check string contain a valid regular expression python

Tags: python, regex

In order to check to see if a string is a valid regular expression python.

Example:

```
asdasd="([0-9]{1})";APRI="([0-9]{9})";ADD="([0-9]{1})"
```

How can i check string is contain valid regular expression ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Apply the [EAFP approach](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp), *compile the expression* and handle errors.

For example, unbalanced parenthesis:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.compile(r"(test")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/so/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 194, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/so/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis
```

Answer (score 1):

[EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp)

Compile it and see.

```
re.compile(asdasd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your regex code in the Online Regex Tester

https://regex101.com/

Your first example:
https://regex101.com/r/gN1tG8/1